# max value from subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, max, min

I would like to get max values from subarrays in array1 array.

```
var array1 = [[4, 2, 7, 1], [20, 70, 40, 90], [1, 2, 0]];

let one = array1.slice(0,1);
let two = array1.slice(1,2);
let three = array1.slice(2,3);

console.log(one);

console.log(two);

console.log(three);
```

in result I had:

```
> Array [Array [4, 2, 7, 1]]
> Array [Array [20, 70, 40, 90]]
> Array [Array [1, 2, 0]]
```

Then I tried to get max values from one, two, and three variables but always is an error [NaN].

```
console.log(Math.max(...one)); => Nan
```

I am not very well in JS, soo for any help I will be greatfull. Thanks

Comment: If you want the first sub-array, simply use `let one = array1[0]`. `.slice(0, 1)` will still create an array with the first sub-array as a sub-array. Therefore `Math.max(...one)` is equivalent to `Math.max([4, 2, 7, 1])`, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `map` function and for each sub array call `Math.max` which will return a single value for a sub array.

```js
const array1 = [[4, 2, 7, 1], [20, 70, 40, 90], [1, 2, 0]];

const maxValues = array1.map(item => Math.max(...item));

console.log(maxValues);
```

`slice` function returns another array. If you have one item into the array, it will return array containing one element.

Answer (score 1):

> console.log(Math.max(...one)); => Nan

Because `slice` returns the array from the input array (i.e. `one` is a **2d array**), you need to get the 0th index

```
let one = array1.slice(0,1)[0];
```

Similarly

```
let two = array1.slice(1,2)[0];
let three = array1.slice(2,3)[0];
```

Now `console.log(Math.max(...one));` will give you correct value

For getting max from all arrays, try

```
console.log(Math.max(...one,...two,...three)); //spread with comma
```

For getting individual arrays

```
console.log(array1.map( s => Math.max.apply(null, s));
```